# How do you parse a street address from a single cell in Excel into individual cells when the address format isn't consistent?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of addresses which are individual strings in an `Excel spreadsheet`:

```
123 Sesame St New York, NY 00000
123 Sesame Ct Atlanta, GA 11111
100 Sesame Way, 400 Jacksonville, FL 22222
```

As you can see above the third address is different. It has a suite number of `400` on what would normally be the `street line 2` line. I am having trouble coming up with a formula that will parse the addresses above into its individual cells: `Street 1` (with `street 2` or suite information in this line), `City`, `State` and `Zip`.

My thought is to start from the right and extract information based on a space delimiter, but I am not sure how to do this. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do a combination of MID & FIND to extract parts of the address,

e.g.

```
=IF(IFERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)),1)=1,MID(A1, 1, FIND(",",A1)-1),MID(A1,1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-1))
```

will extract the address from cell A1, depending of the number of commas it finds (1 or > 1).

ZIP and state won't be too difficult following the above mentioned pattern. I think the problem is extracting the city as you don't know where to set the limit between the city name and the street unless you have a finite set of street types, e.g. ct, st, way etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slightly shorter formula using `SUBSTITUTE()` and `LEN()` in addition to `FIND()` and `LEFT()`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1)
```

The first part which gets executed is:

```
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))
```

Which basically calculates the number of commas in the input string. This then goes into the next formula:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","@",[1])
```

Which substitutes the last occurrence of comma by `@` (if addresses have this, use another character which you won't find in the address).

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",[2])-1)
```

And the last part is takes the characters up to the `@` we just inserted.